# How to use different Oracle schemas in Crystal Reports?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

Is it possible to use different Oracle schemas in Crystal Reports and change between them at runtime?

I have a report that uses three tables. The report was created using one database user schema. In the other schemas that I have to use, the names of the tables are the same. I need to change between them at runtime. Different users get different data depending on the schema they connect to. I set the servername, the userid, the password and then integratedsecurity to false. If I change/set the DatabaseName it doesn't work. 
I use Crystal Reports 2008.

Could you be kind and help me with this?

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use Crystal's database expert - instead, write SQL queries that do **not** specify schema. That way, the query will access the tables in the local schema when logged on to it.

eg:

Existing query:

```
select field1, field2, ...
from user_schema1.datatable
```

- will select data from user_schema1.datatable, regardless of which schema is logged on.

Amended query:

```
select field1, field2, ...
from datatable
```

- will select data from datatable in user_schema1 when logged on to user_schema1, from user_schema2 when logged on to user_schema2, etc.

Comment: Thank you ! Do you think it is possible to change this without having to recreate the report?

Comment: Yes - simply remove the schema name and `.` from in front of the tables in the query.